# get data from array into datalist with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-datalist

I already googled my problem but nothing really helped me.
I need an input field, which also works like a dropdown. So I can write my own data in the input field or select data from the dropdown. I tried with select but then I can only select data and can't write data in the input. That's why I used datalist.
I want to write my data from my array to my datalist like that:

**index.html**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model.person.profession" list="professions"/>
<datalist id="professions">
  <option ng-repeat="profession in professions" value="{{profession.id}}">{{profession.name}}</option>
</datalist>
```

**app.js**

```
$scope.professions = [
  {'id':1, 'name':'doctor'},
  {'id':2, 'name':'farmer'},
  {'id':3, 'name':'astronaut'}
];
```

My data isn't shown in the dropdown. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ng-options for showing the value in drowpdown. Pleae take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NSkz4/27/).

```
<select ng-model="selected">
    <option ng-repeat="value in professions" value={{value.id}}>{{value.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Probably I wasn't specific enough. I need an input field, which also works like a dropdown. So I can write my own data in the input field or select data from the dropdown. I tried with select but then I can only select data and can't write data in the input. That's why I used datalist. I edited my question with more specific details.

Comment: @BlueCat: http://jsfiddle.net/NSkz4/28/ . Please take a look at this fiddle

Answer (score 2):

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller("dataListController", function ($scope){
 $scope.professions = [
  {'id':1, 'name':'doctor'},
  {'id':2, 'name':'farmer'},
  {'id':3, 'name':'astronaut'}
];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<main ng-app="myApp">
  <section ng-controller="dataListController">
     <input list="browsers" name="browser">
      <datalist id ="browsers">
        <option ng-repeat="x1 in professions" value="{{x1.name}}">
    </datalist>
    
   
  </section>
</main>
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<main ng-app="myApp">
  <section ng-controller="dataListController">
     <input list="browsers" name="browser">
      <datalist id ="browsers">
        <option ng-repeat="x1 in professions" value="{{x1.id}}">
    </datalist>


  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `Select` element before `option` . And add `track by $index`inside ng-repeat as well. Else for duplicate data, you will get error.

```
   <select>
        <option ng-repeat="value in professions track by $index " value="{{value.id}}">{{value.name}}</option>
    </select>
```

or,

```
 <select>
    <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in professions " value="{{key.id}}">{{value.name}}</option>
</select>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/28745/

Comment: Probably I wasn't specific enough. I need an input field, which also works like a dropdown. So I can write my own data in the input field or select data from the dropdown. I tried with select but then I can only select data and can't write data in the input. That's why I used datalist. I edited my question with more specific details.

Comment: @BlueCat you should have done that. including me , 4 others came with solution, that works but you don't need that now.

Answer (score 0):

Add `ng-value` instead of value in options

```
<option ng-repeat="profession in professions" ng-value="{{profession.id}}">{{profession.name}}</option>
```

Give your plunkr/code snippet

Answer (score 0):

There must be select instead of datalist :

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in professions " value="{{id}}">{{value}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: {{name}} should be {{value}}

Comment: Your code will not work. inside option it will show like: {id:1,name:'doctor}

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using ngOptions like this:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="option.name for option in professions track by option.id">
```